# Remote I/O Error on I2C Bus Raspi Master Arduino Mega Slave

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, raspberry-pi3, i2c

I have connected my raspi (Master) with Arduino Mega (Slave) and want to continuously transfer the analog readings from analog pins A0-A3 to the raspi. Program runs for some time and the crashes giving me:
[Errno 121] Remote I/O Error

I am suspecting 2 things could be the problem: 1) The while loop => longer sleep times result in a longer running time until the program crashes 2) I read somewhere that the wire library does an onReceive command before it does an onRequest?

Here is my Arduino and raspi code:

Arduino Mega Code
    #include

```
int SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x08;
int analogPin1 = A0;
int analogPin2 = A1;
int analogPin3 = A2;
int analogPin4 = A3;


void setup(){
Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
Wire.onRequest(sendAnalogReading);
}

void loop(){
}

void sendAnalogReading(){

uint16_t reading1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
uint16_t reading2 = analogRead(analogPin2);
uint16_t reading3 = analogRead(analogPin3);
uint16_t reading4 = analogRead(analogPin4);


Wire.write((char *) &reading1, 2);
Wire.write((char *) &reading2, 2);
Wire.write((char *) &reading3, 2);
Wire.write((char *) &reading4, 2);

}
```

This is the script on my Raspi:
    import smbus
    import time

```
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x08

def requestreading():
block = bus.read_i2c_block_data((SLAVE_ADDRESS), 0, 8)

print(block)


while True:
#var = input("Press any key for reading: ")
requestreading()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The could should run continuously however i feel the actual runtime until it crashes depends on 2 factors. Length of time.sleep() in my while loop and if the measured values change much.